# Which API to use to find the information based on NDC code?

Tags: openfda, drugs

I found out that there are two ways to find drug information based on NDC code but I am not quite sure which one to choose.

Here is an example
NDC API - https://api.fda.gov/drug/ndc.json?search=product_ndc:73408-709
Drug label API - https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=openfda.product_ndc:%220573-0134%22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the NDC endpoint would be a logical choice. And you can supplement that by calling Drug Label, too, in case you need additional fields otherwise not provided by NDC (e.g. details from the drug's label).

Comment: Thanks looks like I gotta use two APIs to get all the fields I needed.